# Media App deeplinking in UWP on Xbox

Tags: uwp, xbox-one

We have migrated our app from the JavaScript/HTML old school Xbox One framework to UWP. However, we still want to support the ms-xbl deeplinking:
`ms-xbl-{titleId}://media-details?contentId={contentId}` This protocol is used to launch an app from a media tile on Xbox Dashboard.

The titleId of our UWP (Xbox) app is blank in the console, so we cannot use the Xbox XDK to launch the app from a deep link as we used to. Microsoft wants to promote our app but they require using the ms-xbl protocol, is it even possible to handle (and debug) that in UWP?

Looking at the Xbox One dashboard, I can see apps which seem to support it (Netflix, Channel5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The titleId of our UWP (Xbox) app is blank in the console

The titleID should not be null(You cannot get it from console). You can get it from your dashboard and then add it yourself(like from [Get your IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/xbox-live-service-configuration#get-your-ids)). Are you using XBOX Creator Program? In that way when you enable XBOX Live service you can find your titleID directly from XBOX Live Service part from your dashboard. Then you can add it to your app by refer to [Add the TitleID and SCID to your binary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/get-started-with-partner/add-xbox-live-to-an-xdk-project#add-the-titleid-and-scid-to-your-binary).

Comment: We used Xbox Live in the previous, JavaScript/HTML version of the app. However, when we moved to UWP we are not using any of the Xbox Live services anymore. Do you suggest that we need to enable it first to be able to use deeplinking?